# amazon s3 developer free account for testing purposes

Tags: c#, testing, amazon-s3

I'm supposed to use Amazon s3 in my application to upload/download files. Can anyone guide me if I can have a developer test or sandbox account (free) for development time testing only?

Any reliable library to ease operations using .NET?

And what it'd be if while transferring a file, the connection to amazon s3 server break? Half of file has been transferred and half left... can I resume uploading or downloading, or should the operation be performed from scratch?

Comment: I would guess the downvotes are for having 3 questions in one. You should remove the last two and post them separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With respect to the free developer question, you have to pay for it.  The perks of S3 is that it's very cheap.

[S3 FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/)
[S3 homepage](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)

Answer (score 2):

As part of the [AWS Free Usage Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/), you can get started with Amazon S3 for free. Upon sign-up, new AWS customers receive 5 GB of Amazon S3 storage in the Standard Storage class, 20,000 Get Requests, 2,000 Put Requests, and 15 GB of data transfer out each month for one year.

*Your usage for the free tier is calculated each month across all regions except the AWS GovCloud Region and automatically applied to your bill – unused monthly usage will not roll over. Restrictions apply; See [offer terms](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

For just testing purposes, there are ways to mock out S3.  Examples:

- [ruby gem for mocking out the AWS::S3 library](https://github.com/jkrall/mock-aws-s3)
- [S3 ninja emulates the S3 API for development and testing purposes.](http://s3ninja.net)

Answer (score 1):

There is no generally available free version of S3 for development. Not mentioning [free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free) here as it is available only for the first year.

What you can do instead, and it's forever free, is to use one of the free S3-compatible services:

- [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack)
- [MinIO](https://min.io)
- [OpenStack Swift](http://swift.openstack.org)
- [Cepth](https://ceph.io)

... and some [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3#S3_API_and_competing_services). They do not guarantee 100% API compatibility, of course, but may be helpful for a local development.

IMHO, localstack is the best one here for the development and testing. It provides a [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/localstack/localstack), so using it is really simple. It also supports two dozen of other AWS services, so you are not limited to S3 only. It can be used to develop a full-featured AWS-targeted app locally!

As to you second question about network breaks. Take a look at [S3's Multipart Upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html). It's just the solution you need.